# Faster reading and faster processing

Tags: c++

I have a large file to read line by line and do some processing for each line. I came up with the simplest program in c/c++ like the following, but I am wondering if I can get some help in making it faster (using `threading` or `fopenmp` etc).

```
FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
char line[500];
while(fgets(line, 500, fp) != NULL){
  line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
  /* do dome processing on each line */
  for(int i=0; i<strlen(line)-k+1; i++){
    /* do something for each k-length substring  */    
  } 
}
```

It takes huge amount of time as my file contains 500 million lines. I tried with a smaller file by first storing the lines and then doing processing the lines one by one and that was faster. Here I cannot store all 500 million lines as they will consume huge space.

I am new to programming, so any help to make it efficient will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. C or C++ pick one. 2. if bottleneck is IO speed threading will not help

Comment: Oh! and if you want fater start by removing `strlen()`. It has runtime overhead. Study about c strings to understand how you can take advantage of their memory layout to improve your code's performance. For example, ignore the `'\n'` instead of replaceing it. It can be as slow as 1000 more iterations per file line if you are actually using `strlen()` like that.

Comment: Aside: removing the trailing newline with `line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';` is dangerous because the last line of a text file might not end with newline, and so truncate the text data. Preferable is `line [ strcspn(line, "\r\n") ] = '\0';` This is safe.

Comment: @WeatherVane If performance is an issue, I would not remove the trailing new line, I would fix my algorithms so that they simply ignore it, or stop when they find it.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I agree with that. An example is when splitting a string with `strtok` in which case `"\r\n"` can be in the delimiter spec.

Comment: With the C tag gone, can we assume you have looked into iostream and profiling has found `std::getline` wanting?

Comment: What processing do you actually need to do?

Comment: Trawling through a large file line by line is likely to be limited by the speed of the disk rather than what code you chose to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is more suited for code-review. Anyways, some optimizations you can do are if you are on windows are.

- Use CreateFile with the OVERLAPPED parameter for async IO.
- ReadFile to read a chunk of the file into memory
- Create multiple std::thread's at your ReadFile sub-routine, each at different parts of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) the text file and let multiple worker threads process the data.

Comment: I could try this.

Comment: Just a side note: the time complexity of your worker thread algorithm will also affect the performance. The performance gain through parallel processing, as well as the best achievable time complexity, both strongly depend on the structure of your data.